# Javascript/Node.js regexp optimization: is there any benefits to place regexp outside of function?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, optimization, v8

Most of Node.js top modules I inspect always define their regexp in the module scope, outside the function using it.

For example, few lines taken from [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), the fastest multipart/form-data parser for Node.js:

```
var RE_SPLIT_POSIX =
      /^(\/?|)([\s\S]*?)((?:\.{1,2}|[^\/]+?|)(\.[^.\/]*|))(?:[\/]*)$/;
function splitPathPosix(filename) {
  return RE_SPLIT_POSIX.exec(filename).slice(1);
}
```

Beside re-usability, is there any speed benefits doing this rather than moving the regexp inside the function? Like that:

```
function splitPathPosix(filename) {
  return /^(\/?|)([\s\S]*?)((?:\.{1,2}|[^\/]+?|)(\.[^.\/]*|))(?:[\/]*)$/.exec(filename).slice(1);
}
```

I know that regexp are compiled for better performance. Does that mean the last code snippet needs to recompiled the regexp every time the function is executed? I would guess that most Javascript engine cache the compiled regexp.

I'm specifically interested in V8/Node.js here, but general knowledge about how other engines work can be interesting as well.

Comment: This case is particularly interesting because the regex can match an empty string. The problem may arise with multiple matches when the `exec` is used in a loop, then you would need to manually move the `re.Index`. In this case, there should be no change since the whole string is matched.

Comment: The chances that defining the regexp inside your function vs. outside will make any observable difference in the performance of your application are negligible at best.

Comment: You could do an experiment with 100000 strings with both approaches, and see for youself :) However, it's probably not a [big deal](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: @stribizhev: It doesn't matter even without the anchors, because there's no `g` flag. `lastIndex` isn't set when the expression isn't global. E.g., `var x = /./; console.log(x.exec("foo")[0], x.lastIndex); console.log(x.exec("foo")[0], x.lastIndex);` logs `f 0` twice, not `f 1` then `o 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm well aware of the danger of early micro-optimization, yet I'm still curious about how things work behind the scene. Thanks for finding out the duplicate ;)

Comment: It should be noted that all of that path-related code (including those RegExps) came from node's own `path` module. I merely included the code directly for better backwards compatibility (node 0.10 does not have exported platform-specific `path` functions).

Comment: Thanks for this response @mscdex. If there are no speed benefits at all, it should be just a matter of taste.