# Regex to have a number or a special character

Tags: regex

I have a following regex but it doesnt seem to work as expected.

I want one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one digit or one special character.

The length should be minimum 8 char.

```
(^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$)
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex password Regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems. You have a double backslash in front of your digit specifier - make it a single. Also you don't have an expression for "special characters". I have added an expression to include some special characters - you can adapt that to your need (be careful - some have special meaning, for example `-`).

Demonstration at http://regex101.com/r/kM5xW6

Expression (updated to reflect "one digit OR one special character"):

```
(^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_0-9]).*$)
```

This requires at least 8 characters,  a lower case letter, an upper case letter, and a character from the list `!@#$%^&*_0-9` (which is "one of the special characters or a digit between `0` and `9`).

Comment: Thanks but I want a digit or special character. The above one requires both

Comment: OK I misunderstood. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

a little more efficient pattern = `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_0-9])(.{8,})$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO2jG9)