# Regex Specific Match String

Tags: regex

Would some one please tell me the following Regex?

At least eight or more characters.
At least one lower-case letter.
At least one upper-case letter.
At least one number.

Thanks in advance.

Variation on [Complex Password Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression)

Comment: Did you try something yourself? Mind posting the code?

Comment: You don't need to cram every single bit of everything into a single regex. I strongly suggest you use multiple regexes for your password validation. Validate against one that checks that there's a digit, another that checks for uppercase letters, another for lowercase letters, etc. It will be far more readable, and much easier to modify later if you change your password requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex password Regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression)

Comment: Yes, it would be duplicate of Complex password Regular expression, as that is what I was attempting to do. Andy, it never occurred to me to divide it up, as I was thinking of it as one word. Also, guys, it certainly doesn't seem unclear to everyone else here, not to mention the question was answered.

Comment: @Neftas IMHO Regex questions are usually an exception to 'what have you tried' rule cause the answer is usually very short and doesn't require writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$
```

Comment: You forgot the "at least one upper-case" condition

Comment: +1 good solution, not sure why you got downvoted

Comment: Some people downvote answers on question they deem bad. It's being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) a lot lately.

Comment: And accepted answer says this: **No, that is not appropriate. Answers should be voted up or down on their own merits.**

Comment: I answer a reasonable amount of questions on Stack Overflow, but Regex is not a strong area for me, and this requirement seemed particularly confusing to me. I thought the question was entirely appropriate.

Comment: anubhava: Just tried to explain to @alfasin why this happens, I'm not taking a position in this.