# Test with Regex if a certain number of conditions are met

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to figure out if a password meets several conditions, but not all.

Has to include 3 out 4 conditions

```
a) A-Z
b) a-z
c) 0-9
d) !*?$%&
```

So it's correct if the password has a capital letter, a lower letter and a numnber or instead of the number a special char, ...

Is this possible without writing several OR conditions (a+b+c OR a+b+d OR a+c+d OR b+c+d) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website might give some answers too:
http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

On a side note: Use of symbols, lowercase, uppercase, numbers does increase entropy, but length is much more important. The CorrectHorseBatteryStaple (http://xkcd.com/936/) example was a big eye-opener to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid the issue of using a single regular expression, and simply combine the simple regular expressions together into an array, test the entered-password against that array of expressions using `Array.prototype.filter()` to create a new array from those matches where the individual regular expressions test true (using `RegExp.prototype.test()`):

```
function validateConditions (string, n) {
    // individual tests:
    var capital = /[A-Z]/, // any letter, from the characters A-Z (inclusive)
        lower = /[a-z]/, // any letter, from the characters a-z (inclusive)
        numeric = /\d/, // any number character
        special = /[!*?$%&]/, // any of these special characters

    // an array of those simple tests:
        tests = [capital, lower, numeric, special],
    // filtering the array of tests (to create a new array 'success'):
        success = tests.filter(function (validate) {
            // if the string tests true (RegExp.test returns a Boolean value):
            if (validate.test(string)) {
                // we return true (though any value would be fine, since
                // we're only checking the length of the 'success' array):
                return true;
            }
        });

    // making sure that the 'success' array has a length equal to, or greater
    // than the required number ('n') of matches:
    return success.length >= n;
}

// adding an event-listener to the 'test' element, which runs on 'keyup':
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    // logging the returned Boolean of validateConditions():
    console.log(validateConditions(e.target.value, 3));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/67xpbgLe/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Answer (score 0):

Look into using regular expression [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and see if you can hack together a beast of a regex. I checked google for "regex password complexity" and found similar questions to yours, so I'd start there.

Comment: Lookaheads is interesting but not the solution. Solution was found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression