# Regular expression for password with some characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want the `regex` for `password` textbox with below criteria

- (a) At least One character
- (b) At least One special character
- (c) At least One numeric value
- (d) and the length should be greater than 8 digit

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried something like below and it worked.

**Solution 1:-**

```
 function checkPassword(password) {
        var pattern = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/;
        if (!pattern.test(password)) {
            $(".password_error").show();
        } else {
            $(".password_error").hide();
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:-**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicy4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPolicy4"
        ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
    ErrorMessage="Password must contain: Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 UpperCase Alphabet, 1 LowerCase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Both the solution worked for me, but I preferred the second solution.