# Regex to detect any possible character sequence in QWERTY layout

Tags: php, regex

I need to apply password complexity rules as follows:

- min 8 characters
- at least 1 uppercase
- at least 1 lowercase
- at least 1 digit
- at least 1 special character
- no character sequence like qwerty, asdf

I tried this

```
function valid_pass($password) {
    if (!preg_match_all('$\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$', $password))
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

if(valid_pass($password))
    echo "$password is a valid password<br />";
else echo "$password is NOT a valid password<br />";
```

It works for all the rules except the character sequence. How can I fix this?

Comment: "no character sequence like qwerty, asdf". Are 'sdfg','dfgh', etc, etc... allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex password Regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression)

Comment: Every time I'm faced to a password validator like this I end up with something like `ABCabc123` because my original 20-char passphrase is not considered safe enough. *sigh*

Comment: Add a negative lookahead or even better maintain a list of forbidden sequences and use a simple stripos(). There's no need to overcomplicate this regex.

Comment: Are you planning to do this for every keyboard layout? Tbh, personally, wouldn't bother. Even what you've currently got seems too much.

Comment: Where, in your code, do you think it is looking for "the character sequence"? As far as I can see, you have not attempted to solve the problem, not that your solution has failed.