# Password match method validation javascript

Tags: javascript, passwords, match

It doesn't work properly, I get the Password doesn't match! for each password I write with letters, numbers and Uppercase Letters

```js
var reg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$"/; 

var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
if (pass == "") {
  alert("Enter the user password");
  document.getElementById("password").focus();
  return false;
}

if (pass.length < 8) {
  alert("Password too short, at least 8 characters");
  document.getElementById("password").focus();
  return false;
}
var pasw = pass.match(reg);
if (pasw) {
  alert("Password is valid");
} else {
  alert("Password doesn't match!");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question and properly format your post?

Comment: What is the output? Also use if(pass) instead of if(pass=="") as javascript coerces pass to a boolean value and if the pass is null, empty or undefined it won't enter the if loop.

Comment: @loki  pasw is a boolean value the problem is in the last part of the code with the match method 
 I need to get Password is valid If I write  a password containing Uppercase,Lowercase and number but instead I always get Password doesn't match!

Comment: @NicoHaase I need to get Password is valid If I write a password containing Uppercase,Lowercase and number but instead I always get Password doesn't match!

Comment: maybe you should verify your regex

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @loki thank you I wrote " after  $ that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, Use `var reg = ^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{8,}$` instead of `var reg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$"/;` base on this result :

[Regular expression to enforce complex passwords, matching 3 out of 4 rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466868/1442180)

Second, Use `reg.test(pass)` instead of `pass.match(reg)`.

[JavaScript test() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)

> The test() method tests for a match in a string.
>   This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns
>   false.

```
var str = "The best things in life are free";
var patt = new RegExp("e");
var res = patt.test(str);
```