# getting StringIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, stringindexoutofbounds

I am writing a program to accept user name and password using following conditions- username must be min 8 characters. Password must have min 10 characters, 1 lowerCase, 1 upperCase, 1 digit should present in the password.
I wrote a method setPassword() following all the conditions. When I try to execute I am getting StringIndexOutOfBound exception. I am unable to understand why I am getting that error:

```
public void setPassword(String password)
{
    char ch;
    if (password.length() <= 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= password.length() - 1; i++) {
            ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= password.length() - 1; j++) {
                    char ch1 = password.charAt(j);
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(ch1)) {
                        for(int k = 0; k <= password.length(); k++) {
                            char ch2 = password.charAt(k);
                            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch2)) {
                                this.password = password;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use`k < password.length()` instead of `k <= password.length`.

Comment: Did as you said but getting the same error.D:\java>java Login
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at Login.setPassword(Login.java:44)
        at Login.<init>(Login.java:8)
        at Login.main(Login.java:65)

Comment: Another mistake that presents in the code: according to your description first line should be `if (password.length() >= 10)`

Comment: use a [regex or several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/regular-expression-to-enforce-complex-passwords-matching-3-out-of-4-rules) instead of itterating multiple times thru your string.

Comment: Seriously: this is **not** how you you should do such validation. Write *one* method per rule to check, and then call these methods one after the other. The code that you put down is basically incomprehensible for human readers. You wrote unreadable code. It doesn't come as surprise that you know need *other* people to explain your own code to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the inefficiencies of this implementation, the following line:

```
for(int k = 0; k <= password.length(); k++) {
```

Should either be:

```
for(int k = 0; k < password.length(); k++) {
//                ^ removed the = from here
```

Or:

```
for(int k = 0; k <= password.length() - 1; k++) {
//                                    ^ subtract 1 here
```

For the following string:

```
String s = "this-is-a-test";
```

`s.length()` is going to return `14`. The valid indices of characters in that string are `0` through `13`. The idiomatic way of iterating over an array with a `for` loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++)
```

You've opted to instead use `i <= length_of_array - 1` which is effectively the same thing (albeit more verbose), except for your last `for` loop where you neglect to subtract `1` from the length.

Here is a simplistic method for checking password validity based on the criteria you provided:

```
public static boolean isPasswordValid(String password)
{
    if (password.length() < 10) {
        return false;
    }

    int lc = 0, uc = 0, digit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        char c = password.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            lc++;
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            uc++;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            digit++;
        }
    }

    return lc > 0 && uc > 0 && digit > 0;
}
```

This will return `true` if all of the conditions pass, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I didn't observe that error. Thank You Sean!